# How to Recovering MySQL database or table from XAMPP folder after system formatting

Tags: mysql, xampp

How can I access the database from xampp folder?
I have installed a new one XAMPP. When I copy my backup folder (with the name of my database, containing all .frm and .opt files) to the D:\xampp\mysql\data, the database shows in the list in phpmyadmin but it has no tables and data. What I've done wrong?